# Gpg symmetric decryption reduce the passphrase remember time

Tags: encryption, gnupg

i used this command to decrypt my file

```
gpg -d myfile.gpg
```

it asked me for passphrase when i entered it showed me the content of the file

now when i run the command again it did not ask me the passphrase and directly decrypted the file

how can i reduce the passphrase remember time.

Thanks

Is there any way to do this through command line or every from a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `--no-use-agent` you are always asked for a passphrase:

```
gpg --no-use-agent -d myfile.gpg
```

Comment: c_korn Man you rock !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `--no-symkey-cache` to prevent the passphrase being stored:

```
gpg -c --no-symkey-cache test.txt
gpg -d --no-symkey-cache test.txt.gpg
```